# Mostrar itens em jQuery, usando loop interno

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte jQuery:

```
$(".quantidade_lotes").change(function() {
    var quantidade_linhas = $("#quantidade_linhas").val();
    var quantidade_lotes = $(".quantidade_lotes").val();
    var quantidade_dividida = (quantidade_linhas/quantidade_lotes);
    var quantidade_dividida_acima = Math.ceil(quantidade_dividida);
});
```

Nisto, quantidade_linhas é = 17, quantidade_lotes = 5, quantidade_dividida = 3.4 e quantidade_dividida_acima é igual a 4. Até ai, tudo OK e correto.

O caso é, preciso fazer um Loop, onde eu coloque então 4 itens dentro do HTML. Tentei da seguinte maneira:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= quantidade_dividida_acima; i++) {
    $(".lotes_lista").html("<h1>Título</h1>"+i);
}
```

Porém, ele não exibe os 4, por exemplo, ele insere apenas um. Como eu posso ajustar isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Neste caso, eu seleciono em quantos lotes eu vou dividir este envio de sms, dai quando eu selecionar, ele trará pra mim todas as divisões, conforme o layout..

Este é o código que o jQuery deverá incluir, a cada lote, sendo dividido conforme a seleção.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Lote </th>
            <th> Qtde </th>
            <th class="text-right"><span > Data</span> </th>
            <th>inicial</th>
            <th class="text-right">Data</th>
            <th>Final </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="widget-thumb-body-stat label label-danger btn-circle" data-counter="counterup" data-value="1">1</span>
            </td>
            <td> <span class="widget-thumb-body-stat label label-danger btn-circle" data-counter="counterup" data-value="1080">1080</span>
            </td> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-start-date="+0d">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>

                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn default" type="button">
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        </button>

                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker timepicker-24">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn default" type="button">
                                <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><b>-</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-start-date="+0d">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn default" type="button">
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker timepicker-24">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn default" type="button">
                                <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>                                                       
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Poste o `HTML` desta tela

Comment: Não está muito claro o que precisa ser feito, com o que você já tem e com o conteúdo

Comment: @KennyRafael Veja se ficou mais claro.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você precisa armazenar os valores em um array, e cada vez que você faz o calculo você está sobrescrevendo o valor numa única variável, tente isto:

```
var quantidade_dividida_acima = [];

$(".quantidade_lotes").change(function() {
    var quantidade_linhas = $("#quantidade_linhas").val();
    var quantidade_lotes = $(".quantidade_lotes").val();
    var quantidade_dividida = (quantidade_linhas/quantidade_lotes);
    var quantidade_dividida_acima.push(Math.ceil(quantidade_dividida));
});
//Como o código não possui mais detalhes, 
//penso que talvez este trecho entre em algum outro evento seu
$.each( quantidade_dividida_acima, function( key, value ) {
    $(".lotes_lista:nth-child("+key+")").html("<h1>Título</h1>"+value);
}
```

Comment: Não deu certo, não aparece nada... :(

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo que leia a documentação e que entenda as funções, o que está fazendo não tem sentido:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= quantidade_dividida_acima; i++) {
    $(".lotes_lista").html("<h1>Título</h1>"+i);
}
```

O metodo html não coloca dados, ele sobreescreve tudo, nunca irá funcionar, o correto seria algo semelhante a isto:

```
var dados = "";

for (var i = 0; i <= quantidade_dividida_acima; i++) {
    dados += "<h1>Título</h1>"+i; //Adiciona um item a string
}

$(".lotes_lista").html("<h1>Título</h1>"+i);
```

Comment: Sim, neste caso ele sobreescreve, tens razão, mas da sua forma, também sobreescreveu, qual função que eu usaria no lugar no html? talvez o append?

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o resultado que deseja, já tem itens dentro do div? @AndréBaill

Comment: Então, seria o seguinte: http://prntscr.com/cz9cta ai neste caso, eu seleciono em quantos lotes eu vou dividir este envio de sms, dai quando eu selecionar, ele trará pra mim todas as divisões, conforme o layout..

Comment: @AndréBaill faz o seguinte, edita a pergunta, posta o código e leia isso para deixar as coisas mais claras http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ;)

Comment: Editei, e coloquei a imagem, conforme te passei... pra complicar menos rs

Comment: @AndréBaill tá, le o link que passei e posta o html, fotos nem sempre são intuitivas, vou aguardar ;)

Comment: Ok, está modificado conforme você pediu

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47472/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Comment: @AndréBaill E não esqueça de ler o link que lhe enviei, assim evitará problemas assim no futuro ao fazer novas perguntas, vou tentar entender o código ;)